# "FindExpandablePluginBySpec err:no volume plugin matched" messages in logs while volumes are working

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, kube-controller-manager

Kubernetes version: 1.13.4 (same problem on 1.13.2).

I self-host the cluster on digitalocean.

OS: coreos 2023.4.0

I have 2 volumes on one node:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    name: prometheus-pv-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  hostPath:
    path: "/prometheus-volume"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/monitoring
          operator: Exists
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: grafana-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    name: grafana-pv-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/grafana-volume"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/monitoring
          operator: Exists
```

And 2 pvc's using them on a same node. Here is one:

```
  storage:
volumeClaimTemplate:
  spec:
    storageClassName: local-storage
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: prometheus-pv-volume
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Gi
```

Everything works fine.

`kubectl get pv --all-namespaces` output:

```
NAME                   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                           STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
grafana-pv-volume      1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    monitoring/grafana-storage                      local-storage            16m
prometheus-pv-volume   100Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound    monitoring/prometheus-k8s-db-prometheus-k8s-0   local-storage            16m
```

`kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces` output:

```
NAMESPACE    NAME                                 STATUS   VOLUME                 CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
monitoring   grafana-storage                      Bound    grafana-pv-volume      1Gi        RWO            local-storage   10m
monitoring   prometheus-k8s-db-prometheus-k8s-0   Bound    prometheus-pv-volume   100Gi      RWO            local-storage   10m
```

The problem is that im getting these log messages every 2 minutes from kube-controller-manager:

```
W0302 17:16:07.877212       1 plugins.go:845] FindExpandablePluginBySpec(prometheus-pv-volume) -> err:no volume plugin matched
W0302 17:16:07.877164       1 plugins.go:845] FindExpandablePluginBySpec(grafana-pv-volume) -> err:no volume plugin matched
```

Why do they appear? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is safe to ignore message that was recently removed (Feb 20) and will not occur in future releases: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/73901